# Mostrar los valores repetidos dentro de un array PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando con arreglos en PHP y me veo en la necesidad de evaluar si hay valores repetidos dentro de un array, efectivamente se puede hacer con el siguiente código:

```
$arreglo = ["Luis", "Pedro"];

if(count($arreglo) > count(array_unique($arreglo))){
  echo "¡Hay repetidos!";
}else{
  echo "No hay repetidos";
}
```

Pero, necesito mostrar los valores repetidos que hay dentro de ese arreglo, como lograría eso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Échale un ojo a [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Lo que tú quieres hacer se conseguiría con:

```
array_values(array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)))
```

---

**Explicación**:

Ejemplo:

```
$arr = ['1', '1', '2', '3', '2', '1'];
```

- `array_unique()` devuelve un array asociativo con los elementos únicos y los índices que tenían en el original:

`print_r(array_unique($arr));`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

- `array_diff_assoc()` computa la diferencia. Tiene en cuenta los índices:

`print_r(array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)));`

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

- `array_values()` te devuelve un array numérico, descartando los índices

`print_r(array_values(array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr))));`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```